# does mvc support inheritance of Web.config settings throughout areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I distributed my MVC code into a few different areas and noticed one thing. 
if I have something in the main Web.config, something like:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
     <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
       <namespaces>
         <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
```

those pages that don't belong to the root area know nothing about that. And I have to repeat the same thing in the inner Web.config, the one that sits in the area folder.

How come?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`web.config` inherit but only to subfolders. `~/Areas` is a separate folder from `~/Views` so what you put in `~/Areas/SomeAreaName/Views/web.config` has nothing in common with what you put in `~/Views/web.config`. And because Razor ignores the namespaces section in `~/web.config` you kinda need to repeat it for areas.

In summary you have:

- `~/Views/web.config`
- `~/Areas/SomeAreaName/Views/web.config`

which are two completely distinct folders and sections in them cannot be inherited.

Comment: well, I think it's unexpected and inconvenient

Comment: @Agzam, I absolutely agree with you but once you understand how web.config inheritance works in ASP.NET (using subfolders) and where Razor looks for namespaces you will see that it makes sense.

Comment: Is there a link to documentation regarding this?

Answer (score 3):

I created a function to do this which will use the area web.config if the user is using the area otherwise will use the root web.config:

```
public static T GetWebConfigSection<T>(Controller controller, string sectionName) where T : class
        {
            T returnValue = null;
            String area = null;

            var routeArea = controller.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];

            if(routeArea != null)
                area = routeArea.ToString();

            System.Configuration.Configuration configFile = null;

            if (area == null)
            {
                // User is not in an area so must be at the root of the site so open web.config
                configFile = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
            }
            else
            {
                // User is in an Area, so open the web.config file in the Area/views folder (e.g. root level for the area)
                configFile = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/Areas/" + area + "/Views");
            }

            if (configFile != null)
                returnValue = configFile.GetSection(sectionName) as T;

            return returnValue;
        }
```

And then call:

```
ForestSettings forestSettings = ConfigFunctions.GetWebConfigSection<ForestSettings>(controller, "myCompanyConfiguration/forestSettings");
```