# How to get a value in web.config of an ASP.NET MVC area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [does mvc support inheritance of Web.config settings throughout areas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941879/does-mvc-support-inheritance-of-web-config-settings-throughout-areas)

In [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) 3, I can get the `appsetting` value in the root `web.config`, but how can I get the value in `web.config` which is in area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access any web config by giving virtual path like this

```
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/Areas/AdminPanel/Views/Web.config").AppSettings.Settings["keyName"].Value
```

1. "/Areas/AdminPanel/Views/Web.config" - Virtual Path
2. "keyName" - key 
       of your appSetting